# Nested target batching in MSBuild?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nested, msbuild-batching

I want to execute an action per DeploymentTarget, of which there can be more than 1 per ProjectsForDeployment. I know if there was only 1 DeploymentTarget child per ProjectsForDeployment, the target batching would work - but what happens if there's multiple children? Is it still possible to run ProcessDeployableObject 4 times against A1/A2/B1/B2 whilst maintaining references to the siblings and parent?

Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <Target Name="Deploy" >
    <CallTarget Targets="ProcessDeployableProject" />
  </Target>
  
  <Target Name="ProcessDeployableProject" Inputs="@(ProjectsForDeployment)" Outputs="%(ProjectsForDeployment.Identity)\dummy.txt" >
      <!-- Processing goes here for %(ProjectsForDeployment.DeploymentTarget), needs OtherMetadataWeNeed and ProjectsForDeployment.Identity too. -->
  </Target>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectsForDeployment Include="/src/A/A.csproj" >
      <DeploymentTarget>A1</DeploymentTarget>
      <DeploymentTarget>A2</DeploymentTarget>
      <OtherMetadataWeNeed>Metadata</OtherMetadataWeNeed>
    </ProjectsForDeployment>
    <ProjectsForDeployment Include="/src/B/B.csproj" >
      <DeploymentTarget>B1</DeploymentTarget>
      <DeploymentTarget>B2</DeploymentTarget>
      <OtherMetadataWeNeed>Metadata</OtherMetadataWeNeed>
    </ProjectsForDeployment>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run four times, you should write four items rather than two items.

**In your side**, DeploymentTarget `A2` will be overwritten with `A1` because they are under the same item.

To solve it, you have to separate them which is more like a CSProj running with the DeploymentTarget one at a time. And when you build your project with msbuild command line, each command should work with one Configuration and Platform.

Use this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectsForDeployment Include="/src/A/A.csproj" >
      <DeploymentTarget>A1</DeploymentTarget>
      <OtherMetadataWeNeed>Metadata</OtherMetadataWeNeed>
    </ProjectsForDeployment>
 
    <ProjectsForDeployment Include="/src/A/A.csproj" >
      <DeploymentTarget>A2</DeploymentTarget>
      <OtherMetadataWeNeed>Metadata</OtherMetadataWeNeed>
    </ProjectsForDeployment>


    <ProjectsForDeployment Include="/src/B/B.csproj" >
      <DeploymentTarget>B1</DeploymentTarget>    
      <OtherMetadataWeNeed>Metadata</OtherMetadataWeNeed>
    </ProjectsForDeployment>

    <ProjectsForDeployment Include="/src/B/B.csproj" >
      <DeploymentTarget>B2</DeploymentTarget>    
      <OtherMetadataWeNeed>Metadata</OtherMetadataWeNeed>
    </ProjectsForDeployment>
  </ItemGroup>
```